# fusionauth - after install can't access to setup wizard

Tags: fusionauth

I'm trying to install fusionauth but after install, I can't access to setup wizard.

Here is my fusionauth-app.log

```
...
22-Dec-2019 18:44:21.217 INFO [http-nio-9011-exec-1] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:430)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:684)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you modified your server.xml? How did you install FusionAuth? What URL are you using to access the setup wizard?

Comment: I resolved this issue. I'm using Safari in OSX and in the last version all http traffic is automatically redirected to https but FusionAuth is not configured to use https. To resolve I'm installed Apache with proxy to FusionAuth.